# React router rerenders whole app and resets redux state tree?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

I've have tried to setup React, redux, react-redux, react-router and react-redux-router, but everytime I do a transition from a route to another, the whole app gets re-rendered, How can I fix this?  I mean, what I need to do is at least the top level component to stay where he is and don't lose the redux state tree, because a router transition resets redux state.

These are the version of the packages I'm using:

**"react": "^0.14.6",

  "react-dom": "^0.14.6",

  "react-redux": "^4.0.6",

  "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5",

  "react-router-redux": "^3.0.0",

  "redux": "^3.0.6"**

This is my route configuration:

```
export default (<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="companies">
        <Route path="create" components={CompaniesCreate}></Route>
        <Route path="grid" components={CompaniesGrid}></Route>
    </Route>
 </Route>);
```

My default index.js export:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <div>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes}/>
        <DevTools />
    </div>
</Provider>
, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

my ConfigureStore.js

```
const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistory(browserHistory);
const finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise, reduxRouterMiddleware),
    DevTools.instrument()
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);
    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () =>
            store.replaceReducer(require('../reducers'))
        );
    }
    return store;
 }
```

And finally, the index for the reducers:

```
export default combineReducers({
    ...reducers
    routing: routeReducer,
});
```

Comment: Could you show an example link that causes the transition?

Comment: I'm using material UI Components, here is how I use the link: `<ListItem key={1} primaryText="Crear" linkButton={true} href="/companies/create" leftIcon={<CreateIcon />}  />` @janpieter_z

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the [`ListItem`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/lists/list-item.jsx) renders an [`EnhancedButton`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/enhanced-button.jsx), which has a parameter called containerElement, you can call this with the ReactRouter [`Link`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/modules/Link.js) component. In [their docs for Link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link) they specify how to use it, an example for it is below, you'll have to get react-router's Link component and use that for navigation around your application.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';

render() {
//removed props and other items for simplicity
    return(    
        <ListItem 
             containerElement=Link 
             key={1} 
             primaryText="Crear" 
             linkButton={true} 
             href="/companies/create" 
             leftIcon={<CreateIcon />} 
         />
     );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Using prop this way now: `containerElement={<Link to="/companies/create"/>}`

Comment: but will the store stay there if you go to another route and then refresh the page?

Comment: @jojojohn state gets reset everytime you refresh the page, to keep the state you might wanna try  https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist.